# SSL Error with WCF Service using Transport Security & Cert. Authentication

Tags: .net, wcf, ssl, wcf-security

I don't know if this is a question more suited for Serverfault.com, really depends on the answer, but I have followed [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949005.aspx) in .NET C# to setup a WCF service under 'wsHttpBinding' (Transport Security & Certificate Authentication), I have created a test development certificate using the methods described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949067.aspx) and I have also configured my HTTPS 443 port in Bindings for IIS.

Everything has been working pretty good each step, however I am receiving an error in the the Example "Hello World" service I created (again, all followed via the MSDN tutorial link I first stated) when hitting `https://vd1/WcfWsHttpBindingTest/Service.svc` (VD1 being my local computer name):

```
HTTP Error 403.7 - Forbidden
The page you are attempting to access requires your browser to have a Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) client certificate that the Web server recognizes.
```

I have followed both tutorials as stated to install my [server certificate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949067.aspx) and the [client certificate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949057.aspx) and it has been configured in IIS; Also if I negate the 'https' and just use 'http' I receive a 403.4 Forbidden stating I am trying to access a page which has been secured with SSL, so I'm pretty sure that side of it is working.

Any ideas folks?
I haven't deviated from the tutorials, I am running IIS 7.0 and Vista Business.

It would even help if somebody could start me from a clean slate by giving me better tutorial links for configuring a service with wsHttpBinding.

** **If anyone had seen my initial post, you will notice I closed my answer as it has evolved to the problem above** **

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your help Tanner.

After two hours of scratching my head and tinkering, with help from a colleague we narrowed it down to one step which was not done correctly.  The Certificate was being added to "Local User" not "Local Computer".

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the client credentials aren't getting set or there is a problem with the config files. Can you post the config files so we can see the ClientCredentials configuration, which configures in a tag like: < clientCertificate > .

Alternately, a cert can be configured in code, so if you have the source code that configures the cert on the proxy, post that.

A final check would be Vista Specific. You should run VS (and possibly related processes for certificate generation) as admininstrator: [Some Info on Vista Admin](http://geekularity.com/2007/02/02/installing-self-signed-ssl-certificates-in-vista/)

If none of that helps, try [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/WCFSecurityGuide) for some guidance, I found that the checklists for security configuration helped me no end.

Answer (score 0):

If you are prompted for an administrator password or for a confirmation, type your password, or click Continue. 
2.  In IIS Manager, locate the Web application for which you want to change the SSL setting. 
3.In Features View, double-click SSL Settings. 
4.On the SSL Settings page, select the Accept option under
Client certificates. 5.In the Actions pane, click  Apply